# Delete *.* Local Files in Android programmatically

Tags: android

I am writing an app that stores files locally.
I can delete a file easily by specifying its name

```
 button_deleteFile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String thisFilename=text_fileToDelete.getText().toString();
            thisFilename=thisFilename+".txt";
            deleteFile(thisFilename);
        }
    });
```

Is it possible to wild card delete files to empty the storage space and clean up? EDIT: If so please can you show me how.

Comment: Well why dont you try and tell us?

Comment: You can do a filewalk and get a list of files in a given directory and as long as you have the relevant permission you can go ahead and delete them all.

Comment: @blackapps :-) is it possible to wild card delete files to empty the storage space and clean up?   If so please could you show me how.

Comment: Again: What did you try? Further it is unclear what you mean with `the storage space`.

Comment: @NikosHidalgo I did think of that but its a shame there is not a wild card delete.Unless someone else knows better. Thank you

Comment: @blackapps: I tried searching SO. Storage space: the allocated memory for local storage of files you may want to save in the course of the app usage. Defined as internal storage. This is only accessible by the App.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 delete whole file:

  File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"directory_name"); 
if (dir.isDirectory()) 
{
String[] children = dir.list();
for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
{
   new File(dir, children[i]).delete();
}
}
```

OR

```
  try{
   String d_path = "your file path";
   File file = new File(d_path);
   Boolean isDeleted= delete(context,file );
   }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
 }

public static boolean delete(final Context context, final File file) {
final String where = MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=?";
final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
        file.getAbsolutePath()
};
final ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
final Uri filesUri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");

contentResolver.delete(filesUri, where, selectionArgs);

if (file.exists()) {

    contentResolver.delete(filesUri, where, selectionArgs);
}
return !file.exists();
}
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that come next year with the release of Android R and the takeover of scoped storage, the first option won't be viable anymore.

Comment: @Nikos Hidalgo The first option will still be usable for scoped storage paths.

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() is deprecated in Android 10 and with the  Q beta phases, we were told that we have a year till we switch to Media Store or intent actions.

Comment: @  Nikos Hidalgo Scoped storage paths are getFilesDir(), getExternalFilesDir() and getExternalFilesDirs(). There you can still use classic file paths and the `File` class.  Indeed not getExternalStrorageDirectory() anymore.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I should have been more specific.

Comment: The second option does not delete files from getExternalFilesDir() or getExternalFilesDirs() . Not under Android Q not on below Android Q. It also does not delete files from getExternalStorageDirectory() below Android Q.

Comment: `contentResolver.delete(filesUri, where, selectionArgs);` That returns an `ìnt`. You are not checking it's value.